# Segue to "self" - Transition back to initial controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I would like to have three separate `tableViews`, show the middle view automatically (root view), and access the other two via a button or segmented control. That logic can come later. When I access the first I want it to slide in from the left, when I access the third I want it to slide in from the right to give it the appearance of the middle view controller always being there and only moving left and right via transitions.

Using storyboard segues is giving way to many complications - because my `tableViewController` is the initial root view, there is no way to segue to `self` from `self` when the button or segmented control is accessed. I feel like this must be a semi-standard implementation. Is there a best practice to implement this UI? Should I build my own custom container class and swap controllers and associated view in and out?

Comment: Segues to self?  I think your looking for 'Unwind' to root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 segues from you root to left and right table view. When you would like to go back, to root controller, use unwind segues.

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)